# object databricks is not a member of package com

Tags: apache-spark, stanford-nlp, apache-zeppelin, databricks

I am trying to use Stanford NLP library in Spark2 using Zeppelin (HDP 2.6). Apparently there is wrapper built by Databricks for the Stanford NLP library for Spark. Link: https://github.com/databricks/spark-corenlp

I have downloaded the jar for the above wrapper from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/databricks/spark-corenlp/0.2.0-s_2.10) and also downloaded Stanford NLP jars from [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html). Then I have added both sets of jars as dependencies in Spark2 interpreter settings of Zeppelin and restarted the interpreter.

Still the below sample program gives the error "object databricks is not a member of package com
       import com.databricks.spark.corenlp.functions._"

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.databricks.spark.corenlp.functions._

import sqlContext.implicits._

val input = Seq(
  (1, "<xml>Stanford University is located in California. It is a great university.</xml>")
).toDF("id", "text")

val output = input
  .select(cleanxml('text).as('doc))
  .select(explode(ssplit('doc)).as('sen))
  .select('sen, tokenize('sen).as('words), ner('sen).as('nerTags), sentiment('sen).as('sentiment))

output.show(truncate = false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to downloading the jar file for Databricks corenlp. I downloaded it from this [location](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/databricks/spark-corenlp/0.2.0-s_2.11). Problem solved.