# object johnsnowlabs is not a member of package com

Tags: apache-zeppelin, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am very new to Zeppelin/spark and couldn't get an accurate description of steps to configure new dependencies like that of NLP libraries.
Found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588799/object-databricks-is-not-a-member-of-package-com).

I was trying to use Johnsnowlabs NLP library in Zeppelin notebook (spark version2.2.1).
Setup included :

1. In Zeppelin's Interpreters configurations for Spark, include the following artifact:
   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.5.4
2. Then, in conf/zeppelin-env.sh, setup SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS.
   export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=” — packages JohnSnowLabs:spark-nlp:2.2.2". Then restarted Zeppelin.

But  the below program gives the error :

```
%spark
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.base._
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator._

<console>:26: error: object johnsnowlabs is not a member of package com
       import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.base._
                  ^
<console>:27: error: object johnsnowlabs is not a member of package com
       import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotator._
```

Can someone please share how this can be done? I referred this [link](https://medium.com/spark-nlp/introduction-to-spark-nlp-installation-and-getting-started-part-ii-d009f7a177f3) .
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to edit the `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` (anyway you're using it incorrectly, as you're specifying completely different version), you can make all changes via Zeppelin UI.  Go to the Spark interpreter configuration, and put `com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.5.4` into `spark.jars.packages` configuration property (or add it if it doesn't exist), and into the `Dependencies` at the end of configuration (for some reason, it isn't automatically pulled into driver classpath).